# Why is parallel --nice not setting the niceness?

Tags: gnu-parallel

If I run a command with `nice`, then I can see its process having the expected niceness value:

In one terminal:

```
nice sleep 17
```

and in another one:

```
$ ps -aoni,comm | grep sleep
 10 sleep
```

But trying to do the same with [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) (version *20161222*, Debian 9.3), I fail:

```
parallel --nice 10 sleep ::: 17

$ ps -aoni,comm | grep sleep
  0 sleep
```

I am probably missing something obvious, but what ?

**update:** perhaps it is just a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/889632), because it worked with older versions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have found a bug. Thanks.

It was introduced in parallel-20160522, and until now did not have any automated testing to check that `--nice` was working locally.

Next release will have both testing and `--nice` working.

The workaround for local jobs is to run `parallel` with `nice`:

```
nice -n 18 parallel bzip2 '<' ::: /dev/zero /dev/zero
```

The bug only affects local jobs: Remote jobs are `nice`d as you would expect.

Comment: Oh, I was wondering about this too, but assumed that it was something I did wrong (I'm not a frequent `parallel` user). Good!